# Passing field values into variable and hidden input with Javascript elegantly

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to verify information submitted with a `document.write` and pass the form values into hidden form fields (if it's necessary) for final submittal.  Using an online script I have the field value contained as such

```
if (splitArray[i] == 'textname')    
document.formname.textname.value = unescape(splitArray[i+1]);
```

What's the cleanest way to both print the value on the page in somewhat of a sentence structure, and also ready the values for submittal?

```
...
if (splitArray[i] == 'textname')  
var x = unescape(splitArray[i+1]);
}

function writeIt(y) { document.write(y); }
```

to print on page confirm.html:

```
Hello <script>writeIt(x);</script>, welcome to Wonderland.
```

to pass on page confirm.html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="textname" value="<script>writeIt(x);</script>">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Is passing the values into `<input>` fields necessary, or can I rely on `document.formname.textname.value` to contain the form values (without actually having to write out the HTML (form `<input>`) other than the submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to verify information submitted with a document.write

`document.write` does not "submit" information, it writes to the current document. If the document is closed, it first calls `document.open` which will remove all content.

> and pass the form values into hidden
>   form fields (if it's necessary) for
>   final submittal. Using an online
>   script I have the field value
>   contained as such
>
> ```
> if (splitArray[i] == 'textname')    
> document.formname.textname.value = unescape(splitArray[i+1]);
> ```
>
> What's the
>   cleanest way to both print the value
>   on the page in somewhat of a sentence
>   structure, and also ready the values
>   for submittal?

To display the text in the page, add it as a textNode of an existing or new element:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode('foo bar');
<someElement>.appendChild(textNode);
```

which can be done in one line:

```
<someElement>.appendChild(document.createTextNode('foo bar'));
```

Or you can set the element's innerHTML property:

```
<someElement>.innerHTML = 'foo bar';
```

It seems strange to use hidden elements for the values, then display them elsewhere. Why not just use read-only form controls? Then your text is displayed, it is as safe from user modification as hidden elements are and it's ready for submitting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I want to display them in a different context to prompt the user with "new" information that would actually prompt them to read what they have previously selected.  If I present them with a simple repetition of what they just saw (ie a form with the fields selected) I think people will be more apt to hit Submit without actually reading through it and verifying the information.

Comment: Actually, you are correct in suggestion to make the fields read only.  That does the trick.  Thanks again.